# Blender 2.80 AV Sync missing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I just installed Blender 2.8 and for the life of me I can not find AV Sync anywhere and video editing has become impossible. Is there some new setting I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available in the *Timeline* header menu > *Playback* > *AV-Sync* dropdown menu, it seems like it worked the same in the previous versions, no?

[image]